# Cakephp 2.x - Containable refusing to work

Tags: php, cakephp-2.x, containable

I have the following Model structure:

Models:

- Opening
- Application
- Applicant
- Group

The first three was created on initial setup of the application, with Groups added via the bake script afterwards.

Model associations:

- Applicant hasMany Application
- Application hasMany Applicant
- Application belongsTO Opening
- Opening hasMany Application
- Opening belongsTo Group
- Group hasMany Opening (added after bake script ran)

I am trying to retrieve data in the Application model but I'm having some issues. I can't seem to get to the Group table. I keep getting told the column I'm looking for doesn't exist. My query:

```
$options = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Application.applicant_id',
        'Application.opening_id',
        'Application.value_1',
        'Application.date',
        'Applicant.first_names',
        'Applicant.surname',
        'Applicant.gender',
        'Applicant.id_number',
        'Opening.title',
        'Group.group_xs',
        'Group.group_name'
    ),
    'recursive' => -1,
    'contain' => array(
        'Applicant', 
        'Opening.Group',
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Applicant.id' => $applicant_id,
        'Opening.id' => $opening_id
    )
);
$result = $this->find('all', $options);
```

Error message:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Group.group_xs' in 'field list'
```

I have tried so many different variations of that, it's not even funny. I've tried both with and without 'recursive', with 'recursive' => -1, 0, and 1. I also tried the below variations on the 'contain' key, among many others.

```
    'contain' => array(
        'Applicant', 
        'Opening' =>array('Group')
    ),

    'contain' => array(
        'Applicant', 
        'Opening',
        'Group'
    ),

    'contain' => array(
        'Group'
    ),
```

I load the Containable behavior at the top of my Application model as follows:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable' => array('recursive' => true,'autofields' => true));
```

Can anyone please help. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the containable only works on "has"-relations and not on "belongsTo"-relations.

Try using joining tables https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables